# Change div positions using javascript by changing class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

- New to HTML coding
- I am trying to transform 3 div blocks using css and javascript by changing their class
- block A, block B, Block C
- using one button (Next)

what should happen.

#### Click 1:

block A (Position 1); block B (Position 2); block C (Position 3)

#### Click 2:

block A (Position 3); block B (Position 1); block C (Position 2)

#### Click 3:

block A (Position 2); block B (Position 3); block C (Position 1)

I can make the first click action happen but the second and third click, i have difficulty coding them. Please see my code below and Thank you in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .center {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .topleft {
        position: absolute;
        top: 8px;
        left: 16px;
    }

    .topright {
        position: absolute;
        top: 8px;
        right: 16px;
    }

    #blockA{
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    }
    #blockB{
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    }
    #blockC{
    background-color: green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    }

    .footer {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #eee;

    }
    .holder{
       height:20px; 
        width:100px; 
        margin: -20px -50px; 
        position:relative;
        top:50%; 
        left:50%;
    }

    </style>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="blockA" class="center"  > blockA </div>
    <div id="blockB" class="topleft" > blockB </div>
    <div id="blockC" class="topright"> blockC </div>

    <div class="footer">
    <div class="holder">

    <button class="button" onclick="back()">Back</button>
    <button class="button" onclick="next()">Next</button>
    </div>
    </div>


    <script>
    function next() {
     document.getElementById("blockA").className = "topright";  
     document.getElementById("blockB").className = "center";
     document.getElementById("blockC").className = "topleft";
    }

    function back() {
     document.getElementById("blockA").className = "center";  
     document.getElementById("blockB").className = "topleft";
     document.getElementById("blockC").className = "topright";
    }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you hard code the classes. Each time `next` is called, it does exactly the same thing. So after one click, you won't see any difference.

Here is a code to do what you need:

```js
var classes = ['topright', 'center', 'topleft'];

function next() {
  var c = classes.shift();
  classes.push(c);
  set();
}

function back() {
  var c = classes.pop();
  classes.unshift(c);
  set();
}


function set() {
  document.getElementById("blockA").className = classes[0];
  document.getElementById("blockB").className = classes[1];
  document.getElementById("blockC").className = classes[2];
}
```

```css
.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
.topleft {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}
.topright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}
#blockA {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
#blockB {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
#blockC {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.footer {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.holder {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: -20px -50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="blockA" class="center">blockA</div>
<div id="blockB" class="topleft">blockB</div>
<div id="blockC" class="topright">blockC</div>

<div class="footer">
  <div class="holder">

    <button class="button" onclick="back()">Back</button>
    <button class="button" onclick="next()">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The idea is: you have a list of classes. When you press next, you remove the first class and insert it at the end of the list. When you press back, you remove the last element and insert it at the beginning. So you just rotate your array and then apply your classes. Tell me if you need more explanation.

Comment: Thank you Shitsu!! you made it so simple. At first i used an array like yours "var classes = ['topright', 'center', 'topleft']" but then my code would not work. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

You could make a global variable, and initialize it to a value of zero. This variable will store the number of clicks on the button which you've specified. In the function `next()`, write three blocks of code, each within an `if` statement. These statements will check the value of the global variable, and execute the desired code. If the value of the variable is a multiple of 3, execute code required for click 3 and so on.

P.S. I could write the code for you, but since you're a newbie and this isn't very tough to code, I would want you to write the code yourself.

Comment: What you propose is not really elegant (too much duplicated code)